# Unable to Upload File in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am uploading PDF file in the database but there is some problem all data is successfully uploading but unable to upload file in database

Controller

```
function register_candidate(){

        if($this->input->post()){

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('resume'))
                {
                        $filename = '';

                }
                else
                {
                        $filename = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                }

            $dataArray = array('salutation'=>$this->input->post('salutation',true),
            'candidate_first_name'=>$this->input->post('candidate_first_name',true),
            'candidate_last_name'=>$this->input->post('candidate_last_name',true),
            'nationaity'=>$this->input->post('nationaity',true),
            'candidate_phone'=>$this->input->post('candidate_phone',true),
            'candidate_email'=>$this->input->post('candidate_email',true),
            'candidate_job_title'=>$this->input->post('candidate_job_title',true),
            'salary'=>$this->input->post('salary',true),
            'candidate_password'=>md5($this->input->post('candidate_password', true)),
            'resume'=>$filename
            );

            //print_r($dataArray);
            if($this->Candidate_model->register_candidate($dataArray)){

                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Data Successfully Inserted');
                redirect('Candidate/register_candidate');

            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Failed to insert');
                redirect('Candidate/register_candidate');
            }

        }else{

            $this->load->view('frontend/header');
            $this->load->view('home/register_user');
            $this->load->view('frontend/footer');

        }
    }
```

Only problem with upload data as file are unable to upload and its shows blank data in database

Comment: I never seen someone upload a file "into the database", I think you got this all wrong. The files you "upload" into a folder on your web host, and the "path" of the file into the database, not the whole file...

Comment: Side note: md5 ist not a secure hash, don't use it for passwords.  Use `password_hash` -- with `PASSWORD_ARGON2I` as algorithm, if available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not upload the file to database. Create folder inside your project folder and upload your pdf to it. Then you can insert file name and file path to database as a reference.

```
$time_snamp = date('Ymdhisu');

$filename = $_FILES["file"]['name'];
$filename = $time_snamp . '_' . $filename;
$file = $_FILES["file"]['name'];

$targetPath = 'uploads/Targets/' . $filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
```

Use this to upload your file

Answer (score 0):

**File Uploading Class**

> CodeIgniter’s File Uploading Class permits files to be uploaded. You
>   can set various preferences, restricting the type and size of the
>   files.

**The Controller :**

```
   public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
```

**Load Upload Library :**

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

**Setting Preferences :**

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
$config['max_size']     = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

// Alternately you can set preferences by calling the ``initialize()`` method. Useful if you auto-load the class:
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

> The above preferences should be fairly self-explanatory. Below is a
>   table describing all available preferences.